# TOAD "Never include" option doesn't work?

Tags: toad

My TOAD version is 13.3.0.181.

I set `"object loading"->"Owner name"` option to `"Never include"` BUT the schema name is still prefixes all objects I load!

Is it a bug? Or is there another option to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on 13.2.0.258 and it works properly.

Did you, by any chance, load objects from **files** stored on your hard disk?

Because, this option is related to objects stored in the database, e.g. when you navigate to procedures node (in the Schema Browser), double-click the procedure, and its source is then opened in the Editor.

Doing so, and having the "Owner name" option set to "Never include", will omit owner name from the source code.

---

As you want to exclude schema name from the "Script" tab, then:

- while in Schema Browser, on the right-hand side, when you navigate to the "Script" tab ...
- ... click the first icon in the toolbar - its name is **View/Edit Script Options**
- the very first checkbox under "Create and Drop" block is **Schema name** - uncheck it

That should do.

Comment: I'm in Schema Brower, I select an obejct (e.g. a table), I clic on the "Script" tab and the displayed script contains schema name.

Comment: I see. I edited my answer and added some more info. Have a look.